# Vector not outputting sorted values after sort

Tags: c++

I am writing an insertion sort in C++ and I am not receiving the sorted output, but instead the original input

I have tried assigning the output to a new vector and trying to print those contents out

```
vector<int> vect = { 4, 3, 2, 1, 5 };
vector<int> answer = Insertion_Sort(vect);
print(vector);
```

(I have created a print function), this gives me an error stating

```
'conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'std::vector' requested'
```

and I've tried this

```
vector<int> vect = { 4, 3, 2, 1, 5 };
Insertion_Sort(vect);
print(vect)
```

in which case it just gives me

```
4 3 2 1 5
```

The full code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int Insertion_Sort(vector<int> A){
    for (int j = 1; j < A.size(); j++){
        int i = j - 1;
        do{
            A[i + 1], A[i] = A[i], A[i + 1];
            i -= 1;
        }
        while((i > 0) && (A[i] > A[i + 1]));
    }
    return 0;
}

void print(vector<int> const &input)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        cout << input.at(i) << ' ';
    }
}

int main(){
    vector<int> vect = {5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3};
    Insertion_Sort(vect);
    print(vect);
}
```

I feel like I am handling the functions wrong with vectors, and I don't understand the error it's giving me since I created the vectors as the same type

Comment: you have to take your vector input in the sort function as reference. you sort a copy of the vector and your original vector stays the same

Comment: You need to pass the parameter by reference to see changes outside of your function: `int Insertion_Sort(vector<int>& A){`.

Comment: Also note that `A[i + 1], A[i] = A[i], A[i + 1];` probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: You also don't want a do-while here, but rather a plain while....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few fixes.

First, C++ does not have parallel assignment, like many modern languages. You need to include

```
#include <algorithm>
```

and then use `swap`.

Next use `while` not `do-while`. Insertion sort does not always do a swap on every iteration! Sometimes it does not.

Also, use `void` if you don't want to return anything.

And make that parameter a reference so it actually gets changed.

You should end up with:

```
void Insertion_Sort(vector<int>& A) {
    for (int j = 1; j < A.size(); j++) {
        int i = j - 1;
        while ((i >= 0) && (A[i] > A[i + 1])) {
            swap(A[i + 1], A[i]);
            i -= 1;
        }      
    }
}
```

There are other changes that would be nice, like following capitalization and naming conventions (e.g., `insertion_sort` and `a`) but that's for codereview.stackexchange.com). And you probably should not call `size()` at each iteration as well. Cheers.